# Java complex Math.log function giving wrong answer

Tags: java, math, logarithm

I am running the following function to simulate power flow.

```
Math.log( (1000 * d) / ((1000 * d) - p )) / Math.log(1000/999);
```

I am doing two tests with different values for p

for both:

```
p = 1333
```

test 1:

```
d = 1000000
```

test 2:

```
d = 200000
```

Running through java, both return Infinity

If I put the equation into google, it returns the values I expect. (1386 for test 1, and 162 for test 2)

Equation in google is as

```
ln( (1000 * (1333)) / ((1000 * (1333)) - (200000) )) / ln(1000/999)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are performing Java's integer division with `1000/999`, which must result in another `int`, i.e. `1`.  The logarithm, any base, of `1` is `0`, and dividing by `0` gets you `Infinity`.

Use `double` literals or cast one of the `int` literals as a `double`:

```
Math.log(1000.0 / 999.0)
```

or

```
Math.log( (double) 1000 / 999)
```

Comment: The same problem is happening with the numerator if `d` and `p` are declared as `int` variables. One should declare them as `float` or `double`, or, if that's not appropriate, use floating point literals (e.g., `(1000.0 * d) / ((1000.0 * d) - p )`) to force the type conversion before the division takes place.

Comment: @TedHopp When I ran this code with `int` `d` and `p`, I got `NaN`, presumably because `int` division was occurring there too.  I could only duplicate the OP's `Infinity` if `d` and `p` were already `double`.  But, you're right that it's worth noting that integer division could have occurred there too.

Comment: Right. NaN would be the result of evaluating 0 / 0. I should have realized that since OP was getting Infinity, the numerator wasn't evaluating to 0; hence at least one of `d` and `p` must be declared as a floating point type.

Comment: Precisely the problem, thank you. I'd already set d and p to be doubles because I'd picked up that problem earlier, but forgot that the second Math.log() would be having the same problem.